# Throwing errors while passing .txt file to class object array

Tags: c#, system.io.file

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a file "Additional courses" that has some format error and duplication error. When I import that file into my Course object array, it should catch those errors. I am stuck at how to check for those errors and also I have a problem while importing.

Can someone look at both of those errors please?

```
 public void ImportCourses(string fileName, char Delim)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            int index = 0;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var  array = line.Split(Delim);
                Course C = new Course();
                    C.CourseCode = array[0];
                    C.Name = array[1];
                    C.Description = array[2];
                    C.NoOfEvaluations = int.Parse(array[3]);
                    courses[index++] = C;
                    //Console.WriteLine(C.GetInfo()); 

            }
                 reader.Close();
                  stream.Close();
```

These are the exceptions I want to check for:

1. If number of fields is incorrect the message is “Invalid number of fields in record {record number}”
2. If course code is already used in the course collection the message is “Course code in record {record number} is in use”
3. If the number of evaluation is not a number the message is “Number of evaluations in record {record number} is not in correct format.

I am getting "index out of bounds array" exception and I don't know where to start with the exception.

This is my .txt I am Trying to Import:

[image: This is my .txt I am Trying to Import]

Comment: Your code makes a lot of assumptions that you have the correct data.

Comment: What declaration do you have for 'courses'? That could be a point that raises the IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @RaduUngureanu I have a class named Courses and The class in which i am importing/exporting is CourseManager

Comment: yeah, ditch my first comment.most probably the IndexOutOfRangeException comes from the 6th line in your file. you only have 3 elements delimited by comma, and in code you are trying to access 4.

Comment: @RaduUngureanu I have 4 elements in my txt file CourseCode,CourseName,CourseDescription and NoOfEvaluations
U can check the link i provided

Comment: How about starting with your task? You didn't tell us what your *specific* problem is in implementing the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the array.Length to make sure that you have 4 elements before you try to access them. If the split fails because the data was was empty or the data did not have 4 delimiters, then the array will not be 4 elements long and attempt to access an element by index which is not there will result in an Index out of bounds exception.

here is a potential solution to your problem -- although this smells of a homework problem.

```
public class Course {
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int NoOfEvaluations { get; set; }
}

List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();

bool CourseAlreadyExists(Course course) { 
    foreach (Course c in courses) { 
        if (c.CourseCode == course.CourseCode) {
            return true;
        }    
    } 

    return false; 
} 

// Define other methods and classes here
public void ImportCourses(string fileName, char Delim) {
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            int index = 0;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var array = line.Split(Delim);
                if (array.Length != 4)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Invalid number of fields in record #{0}", index));
                }

                Course C = new Course();
                C.CourseCode = array[0];
                C.Name = array[1];
                C.Description = array[2];

                int evals;
                if (!int.TryParse(array[3], out evals))
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Number of evaluations in record {0} is not in correct format.", index));
                }
                else
                {
                    C.NoOfEvaluations = evals;
                }

                if (!CourseAlreadyExists(C))
                {
                    courses[index++] = C;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Course code in record {0} is in use", index));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: He seems to be a complete beginner. I'm not sure he'll understand the LINQ part. But yeah, this is a solution to his problem.

Comment: You can remove those `.Close();` lines since you have them in using-blocks.

Comment: @LarsTech good catch; they have been removed. I forgot to take them out when I added the using blocks.

Comment: @RaduUngureanu yea i am beginner so i am doing this just with array then how can i replace last part?

Comment: @codechurn thanks it helped a lot!! I am learning languages i am not good at it but i really want to be in this field

Comment: @ShivamSood you can create a method that loops through all already processed courses, and check if C is already in your array.

Comment: create a method:
    bool CourseAlreadyExists(Course course)
    {
        foreach (Course c in courses)
        {
            if (c.CourseCode == course.CourseCode) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

then use the above code
    if (CourseAlreadyExists(C))
    {
        courses[index++] = C;
    }
    else
    {
         throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Course code in record {0} is in use", index));
    }

Comment: @RaduUngureanu I edited my code to include you code sample which removes LINQ part, since as you mentioned -- that is an advanced topic.

Comment: Let's hope understands